# Vercel caching responses for too long

Tags: flask, next.js, vercel

I am running a NextJS 13 API route, where I am setting the following header in the response:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0, s-maxage=1, stale-while-revalidate=0
```

This should cache the response for one second on Vercel's edge cache. I have validated that the header is indeed set.

The issue is that the response is cached for way longer (multiple minutes, at least). I get the response header `X-Vercel-Cache: HIT` for every request together with a `304 Not Modified` status code, even when waiting minutes between requests. This also seems to happen when I set no `Cache-Control` header at all.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to specify [`fetchCache`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#fetchcache). Inside your route file add this line:

```
export const fetchCache = 'force-no-store'
```

Refer this more details: https://vercel.com/docs/infrastructure/data-cache

Comment: This seems to be a step in the right direction. `fetchCache` did not have an effect for me, but `revalidate = 1` seems to. At least for some routes. For others (ones having query parameters) I am getting `X-Vercel-Cache: BYPASS`.

Comment: The latter seems to be due to using the `Request` object (See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#opting-out-of-caching ). It is still not clear to me how I would implemented caching here.

Comment: @Bobface Sorry I don't fully understand. If you want to disable caching for a particular route, either of dynamic 'force-dynamic', revalidate 0, or fetchCache 'force-no-store' should work fine. Or do you want to have a 1 second caching? Regarding query parameters, I don't think vercel fully supports that. There are some old issues open at their repo for caching with query params.

Comment: My goal is to cache the response for one second. This seems to work with 'export const revalidate = 1'. However, this only works when you do not access the request on the server side (like reading query parameters or cookies). This is where I am currently stuck.

Comment: @Bobface That most likely is not supported. Vercel has some bugs with query params. As for cookies or auth headers, it is [mentioned in the algorithm](https://vercel.com/docs/edge-network/caching#cacheable-response-criteria) that caching will be skipped if those are present.